# What causes mongorestore to fail on assertion 17370?

Tags: mongodb

I am trying to restore a dump from a 2.6 Mongo instance to a 3.0 instance.  When I run mongorestore I get this error: assertion: 17370 Restoring users and roles is only supported for clusters with auth schema versions 1 or 3, found: 5

The confusing part is that there were no users or roles on the dumped mongo instance, so why is mongo trying to restore them?

I can't find anything on this.  How can I troubleshoot it?

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure what is the exact cause of the error message mentioned in the question.  I had an empty admin database folder in my backup.  I deleted that, but it didn't solve the problem.  I am guessing that as of version 3 that if you want to restore a complete running server instance with all of its databases, Mongo wants a defined security scheme in place.

I was able to restore the individual databases one at a time using the --db parameter.